# Can "synthetic" be used as an adjective meaning "synthesizing," "that which synthesizes," as in: Write synthetic headlines

Tags: meaning

The idea here is that one should write headlines that effectively synthesize the ideas in the article. Can I express that idea through the phrase: write synthetic headlines?

I assume that I can use synthetic that way based on its etymology, but I'm not seeing any examples or definitions yet that support this usage. Thoughts and comments?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not the best choice, because of the other sense of *synthetic*:

[M-W *synthetic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synthetic)
4.c factitious, bogus

[AHD *synthetic*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=synthetic)
adj. 3b b. Not natural or genuine; artificial or contrived

That is, it can mean *fake*.

Answer (score 0):

I do have one example: in linguistic typology, a synthetic language is a language that uses synthesis, a synthesizing language, where words are more often bound together as suffixes, prefixes, and infixes.

Aside from that one example, I find "synthetic" more usually means "synthesized" rather than "synthesizing". If that distinction is important to you, you might say "Write synthesizing headlines" instead